# Dynamically Add URI to Javascript Adcode

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my AdCode I am just trying to pass the URI to one of the script tags on the code chnm =

I am not sure what is the best way to go about this.

```
  <?php 
  if( aicp_can_see_ads() ) { // This part will show ads to your non- banned visitors

  $channel = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $adCode = '<div class="aicp"><!-- Don\'t forget to add this div with 
  aicp class -->

 <script id="mNCC" language="javascript">
 width = "950";
 height = "900";
 crid = "65743925";
 versionId = "09428435";
 chnm = "<?php echo $channel ?>"; //Used to specify the channel name
 </script>
 <script src="//adserver.net/ads.js"></script>      </div><!-- end of the 
 aicp div -->';
    echo $adCode;
}
 ?>
```

Basically I just need to be able to pass the URI or URL path from where the adcode showed up dynamically to the adserver via the chnm = tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo**

https://ideone.com/TCwY35

**Solution**

You can just embed the variable inside the code using `"'.$channel.'"`

You don't need to separately `echo` the variable. You already `echo` it later.

```
 <?php 

    $channel = "SomeChannel";
    $adCode = '<div class="aicp"
                <script id="mNCC" language="javascript">
                 width = "950";
                 height = "900";
                 crid = "65743925";
                 versionId = "09428435";
                 chnm = "'.$channel.'"
                </script>
                <script src="//adserver.net/ads.js"></script>
               </div>';

echo $adCode;
```

Comment: Welcome Manny, don't forget to +1

Comment: I tried but the system doesn't me due to less than 15 Rep

Answer (score 1):

Just use pure javascript:

```
chnm = window.location.href;
```

but you have a ton of code to clean up to get your example working.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `<?php echo $channel?>` again in PHP tags, you have to use concatenation

Example :

```
<?php echo 'Your name is '. $name .', haha'; ?>
```